# Multiple Easypin images implementation in single page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

- I want to implement this demo for multiple image in single page .given link bellow

  http://atayahmet.github.io/jquery.easypin

  http://atayahmet.github.io/jquery.easypin/demo.html
- Implement one image on single page ,this is working by given code.

[image]

- But problem is here, If multiple images in single page so how can i get coordinate for each image pins .i need to implement this type .

[image]

- I attached code billow for one image in single page , but if i want to multiple images in single page so how can get coordinate of each image ?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://atayahmet.github.io/jquery.easypin/jquery.easypin.min.js">
</script>
```

```
<br />

<div style="position:relative;width:1000px;margin:auto;">
    <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/business-idea-man-technological-devices-600w-137417678.jpg" width="100%" class="pin2" easypin-id="pin2id" />
</div>
<br />


<div class="easy-modal" style="display:none;" modal-position="free">
    <form>
        type something: <input name="content" type="text">
        <input type="button" value="save pin!" class="easy-submit">
    </form>
</div>
<br />
<br />

<div style="display:none;" width="130" shadow="true" popover>
    <div style="width:100%;text-align:center;">{[content]}</div>
</div>

<div class="easy-modal" style="display:none;" modal-position="free">
    <form>
        <h3>type name of hero</h3>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="content" placeholder="type" />
        <br />
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary easy-submit">Save Content</button>
    </form>
</div>

<div style="display:none;" width="130" shadow="true" popover>
    <div style="width:100%;text-align:center;">{[content]}</div>
</div>

<input class="coords" type="button" value="Get coordinates!" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    
    var $instance = $('.pin2').easypin({
        markerSrc: 'http://atayahmet.github.io/jquery.easypin/img/marker.png',
        editSrc: 'http://atayahmet.github.io/jquery.easypin/img/marker.png',
        deleteSrc: 'http://atayahmet.github.io/jquery.easypin/img/marker.png',
        done: function(element) {
            return true;
        }
    });

    $instance.easypin.event( "get.coordinates", function($instance, data, params ) {

        console.log($instance, data, params);

    })

    $( ".coords" ).click(function(e) {
        $instance.easypin.fire( "get.coordinates", {param1: 1, param2: 2, param3: 3}, function(data) {
            return JSON.stringify(data);
        });
    });

</script>
```

Thanks in advance.